# Windows 7 Firewall breaks FTP with TLS Connections

Tags: windows, ssl, ftp, firewall

I'm ever wondering why my FTP over TLS with Total Commander on Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit breaks after a non comprehensible time.
After many hours I found a possibility to reproduce the error with a perl script you can see below.
If the Win Firewall is on it ever breaks on "Durchgang 30", see output below. If the Firewall is off it run and run and run and run....
Active FTP mode brings no change.

Any ideas why the firewall alway breaks at the same point?
Any suggestions what I have to do to resolve this error or any track to delimit cause?

Many thanks!

## The perl Script for Strawberry Perl 5.18.4.1 x64:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use v5.10;

my $debug = defined;
my $use_tls = defined;

print "INC:\n".join("\n",@INC);
print "\n\n";
print "Version Net::Cmd: ".$Net::Cmd::VERSION."\n";
print "Version Net::FTP::File: ".$Net::FTP::File::VERSION."\n";
print "Version Net::FTP: ".$Net::FTP::VERSION."\n";
print "Version IO::Socket::SSL: ".$IO::Socket::SSL::VERSION."\n";
print "Version IO::Socket::IP: ".$IO::Socket::IP::VERSION."\n";
print "Version IO::Handle: ".$IO::Handle::VERSION."\n";
print "Version Net::SSLeay: ".$Net::SSLeay::VERSION."\n";

use IO::Socket::SSL 2.012 qw(SSL_VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE);
if (defined $debug) {$IO::Socket::SSL::DEBUG = 3}
use Net::FTP 3.05;
use Net::FTP::File;

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new(
    '*****',
    Debug               => (defined $debug ? 1 : 0),
    Timeout             => 15,
    SSL_ca_file         => 'test_ftp_zertifikat.pem',
) or die 'Fehler '.$@.' in '.__LINE__;
if (defined $use_tls ) {
    $ftp->starttls() or die "Fehler in ".__LINE__." wegen '$@'";
}
$ftp->login('*****','*****') or die 'Fehler in '.__LINE__;
if (!$ftp->isdir('/tmp')) {
    $ftp->mkdir('/tmp',1) or die 'Fehler in '.__LINE__;
    $ftp->site('CHMOD 0755 tmp') or die 'Fehler in '.__LINE__;
}
$ftp->cwd('/tmp') or die 'Fehler in '.__LINE__;
my $hash_ref = $ftp->dir();
say "dir Ergebnis:\n".Dumper($hash_ref);
$ftp->binary or die 'Fehler in '.__LINE__;
for (my $z = 1; $z <= 40; $z ++) {
    say "\n\n\nDurchlauf $z:";
    if ($ftp->isfile('testdatei.png')) {
        $ftp->delete('testdatei.png') or die 'Fehler in '.__LINE__;
    }
    if (!$ftp->isfile('testdatei.png')) {
        $ftp->put('test_ftp_datei.png','testdatei.png') or die 'Fehler in '.__LINE__;
        $ftp->site('CHMOD 0755 testdatei.png') or die 'Fehler in '.__LINE__;
        $hash_ref = $ftp->dir();
        say "dir Ergebnis:\n".Dumper($hash_ref);
        $ftp->get('testdatei.png','test_ftp_datei.png') or die 'Fehler in '.__LINE__;
        say "dir Ergebnis:\n".Dumper($hash_ref);
    }
    else { say "Datei löschen fehlgeschlagen!"; }
}
```

## Output begin:

```
INC:
C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib
C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
C:/strawberry/perl/lib
.

Version Net::Cmd: 3.05
Version Net::FTP::File: 0.06
Version Net::FTP: 3.05
Version IO::Socket::SSL: 2.012
Version IO::Socket::IP: 0.37
Version IO::Handle: 1.34
Version Net::SSLeay: 1.68
...
...
...
```

## Output of normal continuous:

```
...
...
...
Durchlauf 29:
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> SIZE testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 213 0
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 257 "/tmp" is the current directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> CWD testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 550 testdatei.png: No such file or directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> CWD /tmp
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 250 CWD command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 257 "/tmp" is the current directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> DELE testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 250 DELE command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> SIZE testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 550 testdatei.png: No such file or directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 257 "/tmp" is the current directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> CWD testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 550 testdatei.png: No such file or directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> CWD /tmp
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 250 CWD command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 257 "/tmp" is the current directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PASV
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,***,***).
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> STOR testdatei.png
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:542: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:544: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:566: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:599: using SNI with hostname *****
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:634: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=15
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:677: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:687: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:707: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2505: did not get stapled OCSP response
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> 1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:722: ssl handshake done
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 226 Transfer complete
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> SITE CHMOD 0755 testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 200 SITE CHMOD command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PASV
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,***,***).
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> LIST
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:542: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:544: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:566: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:599: using SNI with hostname *****
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:634: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=15
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:677: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:687: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:707: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2505: did not get stapled OCSP response
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> 1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:722: ssl handshake done
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 226 Transfer complete
dir Ergebnis:
$VAR1 = [
          '-rwxr-xr-x   1 ***** ***          0 Apr 21 06:50 testdatei.png'
        ];

Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PASV
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,***,***).
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> RETR testdatei.png
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:542: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:544: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:566: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:599: using SNI with hostname *****
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:634: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=15
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:677: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:687: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:707: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2505: did not get stapled OCSP response
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> 1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:722: ssl handshake done
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 226 Transfer complete
dir Ergebnis:
$VAR1 = [
          '-rwxr-xr-x   1 ***** ***          0 Apr 21 06:50 testdatei.png'
        ];
...
...
...
```

## Output at Breakpoint:

```
Durchlauf 30:
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> SIZE testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 213 0
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 257 "/tmp" is the current directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> CWD testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 550 testdatei.png: No such file or directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> CWD /tmp
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 250 CWD command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 257 "/tmp" is the current directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> DELE testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 250 DELE command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> SIZE testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 550 testdatei.png: No such file or directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 257 "/tmp" is the current directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> CWD testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 550 testdatei.png: No such file or directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> CWD /tmp
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 250 CWD command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PWD
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 257 "/tmp" is the current directory
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PASV
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,***,***).
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> STOR testdatei.pngDEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:542: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:544: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:566: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:599: using SNI with hostname *****
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:634: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=15
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:677: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:687: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:707: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2505: did not get stapled OCSP response
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> 1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:722: ssl handshake done
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 226 Transfer complete
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> SITE CHMOD 0755 testdatei.png
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 200 SITE CHMOD command successful
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> PASV
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,***,***).
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)>>> LIST
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:542: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:544: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:566: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:599: using SNI with hostname *****
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:634: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=15
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:677: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:687: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:707: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2505: did not get stapled OCSP response
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:667: Net::SSLeay::connect -> 1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:722: ssl handshake done
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x30ca20)<<< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1796: SSL read error
Net::FTP: Net::Cmd::getline(): unexpected EOF on command channel: Bad file descriptor at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Net/FTP/dataconn.pm line 82.
dir Ergebnis:
$VAR1 = [
          '-rwxr-xr-x   1 ***** ***          0 Apr 21 06:50 testdatei.png'
        ];

Net::FTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel: Bad file descriptor at script.pl line 53.
Net::FTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel: Bad file descriptor at script.pl line 53.
Fehler in 53 at script.pl line 53.
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2635: free ctx 36702656 open=36702656
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2640: free ctx 36702656 callback
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2647: OK free ctx 36702656
```

Comment: It looks like the FTP control connection gets closed which is strange. Can you reproduce this problem without SSL? Do you see any problems on the server side?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Without TLS I have no error or break. Only with TLS I get break on 30th. There are no Problems on the server side.